# Visual Studio Using a lot of CPU power

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am using Visual Studio IDE and I have a little problem. The application uses around 20 - 28 % of CPU which causes some extreme delay. I've no idea what is the problem , but it is extremely frustrating. [Here is a picture of my Task Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDpsh.png)

If anyone could suggest solutions to solve this problem, it would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Check to make sure your CPU is not overheating. That can lead to excessive CPU consumption and poor performance.

Comment: Nope, everything is alright with my CPU. I only have this problem with Visual Studio all other applications do not cause a high CPU increase.

Comment: Are you using any plugins?  Does this happen with no solution loaded?  What about with a newly created solution?

Comment: @ValdasVabolis Did you actually measure the CPU temperature or physically check the cooling? For example, your screen shot shows task manger itself showing 2.5% CPU usage. That's very unusually high.

Comment: This happens immediately after I start the application. I had a hello word program so my code probably isn't causing the CPU increase.

Comment: @David Schwartz Hm, I actually even have a computer fan so the CPU should be fine. My Pc is sometimes really weird, I've no idea what is up. Also, the task manager is only 0.6 % now.

Comment: @ValdasVabolis Check the CPU temperature.

Answer (score 0):

Bumping an old thread because I found a strange answer to this problem. My CPU was overheating whenever I ran VS, but the answer had nothing to do with VS...it had to do with dust in my tower.

A $5 compressed air can and a few well-placed sprays on your CPU/tower/power supply fans did the trick for me.

Answer (score -2):

The task manager details are related to VS when VS is not doing anything or its compiling or running stuff.
Also if its running stuff, do you have any thread which is running a very long or infinite loop